# Issue attaching CSV file to E-Mail Objective - C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, csv, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the following IBAction to attach a CSV file consisting of some simple receipt data to an e-mail, however when the e-mail composer view opens, a greyed out file appears in the body section and when I actually send the message the message sends with no attachment at all.

Heres my code:

```
    - (IBAction)actionEmailComposer {
    NSLog(@"Receipts Count: %d", [receipts count]);
    //Create CSV File
    NSMutableString *csvString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [csvString appendString:@"Date,Business,Category,Paid By,Note, Number,Currency, Amount"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [receipts count]; i++){

        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] receiptDate]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] business]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] category]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] paidBy]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] note]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] number]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] currency]];
        [csvString appendString: [[receipts objectAtIndex:i] amount]];

    }

    [csvString writeToFile:@"test.csv" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//        NSString *recipient = [defaults objectForKey:@"reportsEmail"];
        NSString *recipient = @"testemail@live.com";
        NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setSubject:@"CSV Export"];
        [mailViewController setToRecipients:recipients];
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
        mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"test.csv"];

        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:myData 
                                     mimeType:@"text/csv" 
                                     fileName:@"test"];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];

    }
    //Display alert to the user
    else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't Send Mail"
                                                            message:@"Device is unable to send email in its current state." 
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }

}
```

csvString outputs :

Date,Business,Category,Paid By,Note, Number,Currency, Amount"July 17, 2012","tho","Category 1","Cheque","lunch","726269","GBP","100.00"

So there is existing data, it just doesn't seem to attach properly, can anyone explain whats going on here?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: That's a *terrible* way to build the `stringToWrite`. For the sake of my peace of mind, please at least use a mutable string and append to that.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my code for your peace of mind, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I feel relieved ;) I assume you left the quotes and so away for brevity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
            arr_email=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[objDatabase lookupAllForSQL:@"select * from password"]];


    NSString *mystr=@"";
    NSString *str_type;
    NSString *str_name;
    NSString *str_user;
    NSString *str_pwd;
    NSString *str_url;
    NSString *str_descr;
    NSString *csvstr;

    csvstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account Type,Account Name,UserName/Card No,Password/Pin No, URL/Other Info,Description"];

    for (int i=0; i<[arr_email count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arr_email objectAtIndex:i];

        str_type=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"AccountType"]];
        str_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"AccountName"]];
        str_user=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"UserName"]];
        str_pwd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Password"]];
        str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Url"]];
        str_descr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Description"]];

         mystr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",mystr,str_type,str_name,str_user,str_pwd,str_url,str_descr];

    }
    csvstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",csvstr,mystr];   
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Private Closet.csv"]];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    BOOL written = [csvstr writeToFile:filename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!written)
    NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", error);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's counterintuitive, but the file name when you attach the file does not include the extension. Thus, with a file name called "test.csv":

```
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:myData 
                             mimeType:@"text/csv" 
                             fileName:@"test"];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it didn't change anything..  I've edited my code to incorporate the change though.

Comment: Can you verify that the file is written and contains the right data? Also, make sure `myData` contains something. (I used `dataWithContentsOfURL` and it worked.)